# C++ macro with 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2013

I'm using: Windows 10, C++, Visual Studio 2013.

I'm looking for a way to access my 2D-array with negative numbers, for example I know this works with a 1D-array:

```
int myarray[35];

#define a (myarray + 50)

a[-45] = 0; //accesses myarray[5]
```

but can't figure out how to make it work with a 2D-array:

```
int foo[32][32]

#define bar (foo + 50)(foo + 50)

// The above does not work
```

Comment: This doesn't make a ton of sense. Even with your 1D-array if you access `a[-5]` you've done an out of bounds request.

Comment: Why would -45 give you item 5? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Because of the define in the line above.. it works..

Comment: Okay, makes perfect sense! Here is the correct solution for setting index 5 to value 123 while using a negative index:  `(??--5)[array- -!! array] = 123;`.

Comment: It does work, I just can't see why it's valuable. Perl for example allows negative indexes to access begining from the end of the array: http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Subscripts That is an incredibly helpful tool, but only because it's based on the size of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the same approach with 2D arrays as `define`s may have arguments:

```
int a[100][100];
#define b(x,y) a[x + 50][y + 50]

a[0][0] = 123;
cout << b(-50, -50) << endl; // prints 123
```

I personally would not like using this `define`-driven method as this limits the operations you could perform on your array (for example, you can't write `b(1)` to mean one specific row `a[51]` or have to define another macro for it).

To improve readability and maintainability, consider writing your own class, based on `std::vector`:

```
template<typename T>
class ShiftedVector {
private:
    int shift;
    std::vector<T> storage;
public:
    T& operator[] (int idx) {
        return storage[idx + shift];
    }
    // Definitions of other useful operations
}

ShiftedVector<ShiftedVector<int>> x; // Usage
```